# How to get last 5 character Office license key only using script

Tags: windows, cmd, ms-office

I use the below command to get the last 5 char of the office key.

```
cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus >> key.txt
```

Result in the text file:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

---Processing--------------------------
--------------------------------------- PRODUCT ID: 00216-40000-00000-AA541 SKU ID: b322da9c-a2e2-4058-9e4e-f59a6970bd69 LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeProPlusVL_KMS_Client edition LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel LICENSE STATUS: 
---LICENSED---  Last 5 characters of installed product key: GVGXT ........
```

How I can get "GVGXT" only instead of getting a lot of information. I was trying to read the key.txt and only get "GVGXT" then store in csv.

Comment: We need to know the structure of the `csv` file in order to append a new line. Just curious do you want to get just the last key appended on `key.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return the last key appended on `key.txt`,

```
@echo off

setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G IN ('findstr /C:"Last 5 characters of installed product key:" ^<key.txt') do ( set "key=%%G" )
set "key=%key: =%"
echo %key%
```

We can go without a file,

```
@echo off

setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G IN ('cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus ^| findstr /C:"Last 5 characters of installed product key:"') do ( set "key=%%G" )
set "key=%key: =%"
echo %key%
```

Answer (score 0):

To process a file (or a command's output), use a `for /f` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%a in ('cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus') do set "key=%%a"
set "key=%key: =%" & REM remove spaces
echo ---%key%---
```

The `for` loop extracts the second "token" by splitting the lines by `:` and `.` (It does that for each line, but the variable gets overwritten each time, resulting in catching the second token of the last line). Then simply remove the remaining spaces.

(You could even just use `"tokens=9"`, which uses default delimiters SPACE, TAB, COMMA, but I don't recommend that because I don't know if all of your machines return English text and the word count in other languages would probably differ.)

Answer (score 0):

There may be several products.

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter 'ProductKeyId != NULL') |
    Select-Object -Property Description,PartialProductKey
```

This can be placed into a .bat script file or at the cmd.exe command line.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-WmiObject -Class SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter 'ProductKeyId != NULL') |" ^
    "    Select-Object -Property Description,PartialProductKey"
```